# Extract coordinates from src of a Google Maps img

Tags: php, regex, string, google-maps, split

I want is to get the coordinates from a string (grabbed from the src of a Google Maps img). Below is a poor try of mine with regex that doesn't work.

So, what is the best way to do this? With regex? In that case how should be composed?

```
$string = "//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&amp;center=56.393906,16.066206&amp;zoom=12&amp;size=344x170&amp;language=sv&amp;markers=56.393906,16.066206&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;scale=1";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/center=(.*?)\zoom/s', $string, $matches);

... ?
```

**Wanted end result:**

```
$coordiates = (
    [0] = '56.393906',
    [1] = '16.066206'
);
```

Comment: Try `/(?<=center=).*?(?=&)/`. Explode the match by the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use a regex for something like this as it would be slower and more prone to break if URL changes. PHP has built in functions already for such a thing. Use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/parse_str) to easily accomplish it.

```
$string = "//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=56.393906,16.066206&zoom=12&size=344x170&language=sv&markers=56.393906,16.066206&maptype=roadmap&scale=1";

parse_str(parse_url($string, PHP_URL_QUERY), $vars);

print_r($vars);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [sensor] => false
    [center] => 56.393906,16.066206
    [zoom] => 12
    [size] => 344x170
    [language] => sv
    [markers] => 56.393906,16.066206
    [maptype] => roadmap
    [scale] => 1
)
```

So to get your coordinates just do:

```
$coords = explode(',', $vars['center']);
print_r($coords);

// Outputs:
Array
(
    [0] => 56.393906
    [1] => 16.066206
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect but it should work for you with a little modification.  It also shows a simple extendable regexp you can use to break down the map urls.

```
$data = preg_replace('/.*?center=(.*?)\,(.*?)&amp(.*?)/g', '$1~$2~$3~', $string);
$coordinates = explode('~', $data);

echo "X: " . $coordinates[0] . "<br />Y: " . $coordinates[1];
```

- Edited
  Fixed the typos

Comment: You should test the code. Missing semi-colon after first line, preg_match() needs 3 arguments you only supplied 2, there is no such thing as the 'g' modifier in PCRE. There are other errors as well, I tried to fix the code for you, but I'm not sure exactly how you were trying to go about doing this.

Comment: You're still using the 'g' modifier which there is **no such thing** see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php . Please test your code with error reporting at E_ALL, none of this will even execute properly as there are multiple errors still.

Comment: What you want is this `preg_match('/center=([^,]+),([^&]+)/', $string, $coords); echo 'X: ' . $coords[1] . '<br />Y: ' . $coords[2];`. Regardless, a regex should not be used for this task as PHP has functions to accomplish this that does not require invoking the PCRE engine and is more reliable.